# Cannot delete pictures

Tags: ios, uicollectionview

I am trying to delete the pictures that I have taken.  I am saving the pictures in the documents.  I am displaying all the pictures in one collection view and making the user tap to delete to delete the picture. This is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    allImagesArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSArray *locations = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"Bottoms", @"Dress", @"Coats", @"Others", @"hats", @"Tops",nil ];
    NSString *fPath = documentsDirectory;
    NSMutableArray *trashCan = [NSMutableArray array];
    NSArray *directoryContent;
    for(NSString *component in locations){
        NSString *TrashBin = [fPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:component];
        NSArray *directoryContent = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] directoryContentsAtPath: TrashBin];
        collectionTrash.delegate =self;
        collectionTrash.dataSource=self;
        for(NSString *str in directoryContent){
            NSLog(@"str:%@", str);
            NSString *finalFilePath = [TrashBin stringByAppendingPathComponent:str];
            NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:finalFilePath];
            [trashCan addObject:finalFilePath];
            if(data)
            {
                UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
                [allImagesArray addObject:image];
                NSLog(@"array:%@",[allImagesArray description]);
            }}}
    Trash = trashCan;
    for(NSString *folder in locations) {

        for(NSString *file in directoryContent) {

            // load the image

        }
    }}

- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView
{
    NSLog(@"j");
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return [allImagesArray count];


}



-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *reuseID = @"ReuseID";
    TrashCell *mycell = (TrashCell *) [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:reuseID forIndexPath:indexPath];
    UIImageView *imageInCell = (UIImageView*)[mycell viewWithTag:1];
    imageInCell.image = [allImagesArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"a");
    return mycell;
}
//この下のコードではタップ消去をするためのコードです。

-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    NSLog(@"s:%d", [Trash count]);
    NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);
    [allImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
    [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]];
}
NSString *myFileName;
-(void) deleteMyFiles:(NSString*)filePath {
    NSError *error;

    if([[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:filePath]) {
        [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtPath:filePath error:&error];
    }
}
```

However only one picture is deleted at a time. Meaning when the first picture that I tapped only gets deleted and the second picture that the user taps does not get deleted.  How should I revise my code?

Answer (score 0):

I think you forget to update the Trash array, just have a try with this code:

```
-(void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    [collectionView performBatchUpdates:^{

        NSLog(@"s:%d", [Trash count]);
        NSString *trashBin = [Trash objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        NSLog(@"k%@l",trashBin);

        //Don't forget to update Trash here:
        [Trash removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [allImagesArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        [self deleteMyFiles:trashBin];
        [collectionView deleteItemsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:indexPath, nil]];

    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

    }];
}
```